# Audio stops playing while moving to fallback mount using Icecast

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, icecast

I was wondering if someone has had a similar problem:

I have defined fallback mounts in Icecast2 so that one major stream plays at all times. If another fallback mount becomes active, the latter becomes the active. 
I have tested the streams (mp3 format), with ffplay and the transition happens with no problem. The problem exists when I use an html5 audio tag to listen to the audio: transition does not happen automatically and I have to reload the browser and click play in order to listen to the stream. That is, using the browser, when the fallback stream gets enabled, the sound stops and I have to reload the browser and click play in order to listen[to the other stream]. The same problems occurs in all major browsers.

Here's an excerpt from my icecast.xml:

```
<mount>
  <public>0</public>
  <mount-name>/stream</mount-name>
  <hidden>0</hidden>
</mount>

<mount>
  <public>0</public>
  <mount-name>/stream1</mount-name>
  <fallback-mount>/stream</fallback-mount>
  <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
  <username>stream1</username>
  <password>pass</password>
  <hidden>0</hidden>
</mount>
```

This is what ffplay shows while connecting and disconnecting from the secondary source:

[image]

The html5 code that plays the audio is as follows:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://127.0.0.1:3333/stream1" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: So you are streaming MP3 and are playing it back in an <audio> tag? Does it happen on all browsers or on a particular browser? Do the two streams differ in any of the codec parameters? Can you provide a stream dump of a transition?

Comment: Yes I am streaming to the base mount point mp3 with ezstream and to the second mount point with mixxx. To make things simple, I stream the same file (same bit rate, etc). My scenario is as follows: I stream constantly to main mount point with ezstream and I connect to the second mount with Mixx. I have d

Comment: You've tagged this question with JavaScript and HTML5, but I don't see any code in those languages in your question. Can you add in any relevant JavaScript/HTML markup you have?

Comment: Try with an streaming format that is officially supported by Icecast, e.g. Vorbis or Opus. The major browsers support that: Firefox, Chrome and also e.g. Opera

Comment: Same problem with ogg stream. Html5 audio tag with source src="http://127.0.0.1:3333/stream1" type="audio/ogg">
</audio> plays fine but it stops on transition. Have to reload the browser to listen to the fallback stream. I guess it requires more work on client side: eg write javascript code to watch for stream incontinuity and reset audio source programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

I got this finally working by going as follows:

First I noticed that when I switched from one mount point to another by enabling the source, the audio stopped playing. I set up a timer to fire every 1 second in order to check audio.currentTime and compare to an previous value. Then when the result is true, I reset the audio source to the same stream. It's kind of a hack but it seems to solve the trick.

**html code:**

```
  <audio id="audio" controls>
      <source src="http://127.0.0.1:3333/stream1" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>
```

**javascript code:**

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
var oldTime = "";

function myTimer() {
  if ((audio.paused != true && (audio.currentTime - oldTime) == 0 )) {
    audio.src="";
    audio.src="http://127.0.0.1:3333/stream1";
    audio.play();
    }
    oldTime = audio.currentTime;
};
```

Comment: Same issue here, but only in Firefox, both in Windows and Linux. It seems Chrome has fixed it in the meantime. Your hack is very elegant. We will have to apply it until browsers catch up. Thanks for posting this answer.